# Dynamics CRM - Business Rules don't Lock Header Fields

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

Dynamics CRM - Business Rules don't Lock Header Fields

Is there anyway to use a Business Rule and have it "work" against fields in the Header? Or documentation that acknowledges/explains this behavior?

Situation:

- Field "Owner" in Header of Account Form
- Business Rule Locks that field if "Customer" = Yes (Customer is in the Body, not Header)
- I set "Customer" = Yes
- Field "Owner" in Header of Account Form - is NOT Locked
- If I put a copy of "Owner" in the Body, THAT instance of the field IS Locked

What's going on?

Comment: I also opened this as an issue on CRM GitHub https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/dynamics-365-customer-engagement/issues/2717

Comment: as far as I know you cannot hide/show Header fields via BR, reason if you look at schema name for header it would be header_OwnerId but on from it would be OwnerId or something. Strange but yes not via BR, you will have to user Javascript.